# Folder Browser Dialog in outlook Addin

Tags: c#

I Developing an outlook addin where I want to give user the control of browsing the directories and create and a new folder. While navigating through the toolbox of outlook ribbon, I am not able to see any such control but i see the required control in windows form toolbox but I am not able to add it in the outlook ribbon therefore the folder browser is not visible at run time. Need a quick help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a ribbon control and load it to Outlook at run-time. then programmatically prompt folder browser dialog box.

Refer [this MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx) for how to add a ribbon control.

Once you successfully create a button, add the following code for your button callback. This will prompt a folder browser dialog that will allow you to create new folder.

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd= new FolderBrowserDialog();
fbd.RootFolder = System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
fbd.Description = "Your random description";
fbd.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
```